# Calling a json file from Ajax, and displaying data using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Json file containing called services.json:

```
{
"0": "Dog",
"1": "Cat",
"2": "Pony"
}
```

Html:

```
   <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group" id="radiobuttongroup">
                        <label for="inputservice" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Service</label>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio" class="buttondog" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Dog">
                                Dog</label>
                            </div>
                        <label for="inputservice" class="col-sm-2 control-label">&nbsp</label>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio" class="buttoncat" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="Cat">
                                Cat</label>
                            </div>
                        <label for="inputservice" class="col-sm-2 control-label">&nbsp</label>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio" class="buttonpony" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="Pony">
                                Pony</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <span id="displayresults"></span>
```

Jquery im trying:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.buttondog').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "services.json",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                     $('#displayresults').html(json.dog);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried a lot of things however nothing worked. This seemed to cut a lot of the irrelevant script, but even this isn't working. I was then intending to make a script for each button using this method.
What i wanted was that once the dog radio button was selected, 0 would display in the span, when cat, 1 and when pony 2.

Am i doing something completely wrong?

Comment: If your service is returning `JSON` you don't need to parse it just set `dataType: "json"` then data will automatically be converted into a javascript object representing the `JSON` return...

Comment: First of all, if your ajax is collecting JSON data, your `dataType` attribute should be `json`.
For your problem, to print a JSON into an HTML you should use a template. Look for `jsrender` to know how to do it.

Comment: Is your ajax call successful?

Comment: Im not really sure... Im still quite new to ajax, so i dont know how to check

Comment: check console for error(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script, but this is not the recommended way to do things. The parameters which you want to query should be the key for the required values.

```
var data = {
"0": "Dog",
"1": "Cat",
"2": "Pony"
}; // Replace this with your ajax call

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on("click", function(e){
         for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
             if(data[""+i] == $(this).attr("value")) {
                 $("#displayresults").html(i);
             } else {
                 continue;
             }
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just tried it, and nothing displays into the span still. I also dont want to try and put all the data in jquery as im trying to learn how to call from ajax. But thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I meant to replace your ajax call with my hard coded data variable.